# Android DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialog, dialogfragment

I use a class which extends DialogFragment, and in this class I use an `AsyncTask` for loading the content of my `AlertDialog`.
My question is: how I can create an `AlertDialog` which shows: "Loading..." and then shows the content in my `onPostExecute` method?

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public MyDialog(){
       super();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

       ....

       return builder.create();
    }

    public class myTask extends Asynctask<Void, Void, Void> {

       @Override
       protected Void onPreExecute(){
           Show loading... in AlertDialog
       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
           Load content...
       }

       @Override
       protected Void onPostExecute(){
           Show content in AlertDialog
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that purpose, my suggestion is that don't use AlertDialog. Use a progress dialog, Here is your complete dialog,

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public MyDialog(){
       super();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog_id, container, false);
        new myTask().execute();
        return view;    
    }

    private void afterContentLoad (Object content)
    {
        //Update your UI with respect of your content :)
    }

    public class myTask extends Asynctask<Void, Void, Void> {
       private ProgressDialog mDialog;
       @Override
       protected Void onPreExecute(){
           try{
              mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Loading...!");
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               //BadTokenException
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
           Load content...
       }

       @Override
       protected Void onPostExecute(){
           if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()){
               mDialog.dismiss();
           }
           //Put your code after content loaded
           afterContentLoad(Object);
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: You don't need the OnCreateDialog method ?

Comment: Thanks ! But I would like put my content after is loaded into a Dialog, Can I put my content to the progressDialog ?

Comment: And where I call the asynctask ? I use MyDialog fragment = new MyDialog(); fragment.show(fragmentManager, "show"); Currently I put the content into an AlertDialog

Comment: Don't put your content in AlertDialog, put it in DialogFragment because you cannot customize AlertDialog as much as DialogFragment

Comment: Thanks but How I can put it after the content is loaded ?

Comment: Thanks bro :) Now my last question is : where I call the asynctask class ?